# How long is men’s Giant Slalom at the Olympics (Ice River)

Tags: olympics, skiing

While I found some info about the Ice River track, on steepness (68°, seems absurd, and I could not verify) and vertical drop (424m), I’m wondering about the length of the track, esp. for Giant Slalom. Does anybody know? Can’t find it on Wikipedia or the official 2022 Winter Olympics.

Given that it takes skiers some 1.03 min to get down and that their speed is roughly 40m/s (a total guess), this would give a ballpark figure of 2.6km. But from what I’m seeing on live coverage, that doesn’t seem right. Also, that wouldn’t sit right with the assumed 68° decay.

I’m mainly curious since I’d like to figure out how fast the Olympic skiers were going.

Comment: 40m/s is very fast for an unpowered human. Wikipedia indicates 40 km/h is a quite good average speed, and that's almost four times slower than your estimate.

Comment: @Nij, honestly, I don’t know how fast they go. I know I’ve skied myself over 40km/h, and I’m not very good, so they must go faster. Some pages say they reach 90mph, others 150km/h, yet others give maxes of 80km/h. So I’ve no idea and you’re probably right that 40m/s is too high. If I knew the length of the track, we can deduct the avg speed.

Comment: Btw, for comparison, bob-sleighing goes to over 120km/h, and while that’s smoother, it’s much less steep. Also takes about 1min for a 1615m  track (but with only 121m  vert drop).

Comment: I highly doubt there's any official length measurement for any ski course. How would you measure it exactly, given that there can be an infinite number of legal paths taken by the skiers, and the length of each path would also be impacted by bumps/dips on the course?

Comment: @Abel Those very high speeds are for downhill; (giant) slalom being a technical discipline rather than a speed discipline is _much_ slower. As noted by Nij, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_slalom#Speed) states an average speed of 40 km/h = 11 m/s for giant slalom, so handwaving a bit you want to reduce your length estimate by a factor of 4.

Comment: Note the vertical drop is the primary measurement - distance for the course is not regulated, see [this page for example](https://skiproguru.com/alpine-skiing-world-cup-courses-rules-length-drops-gates-and-more/).  So it may be difficult to determine.